# Polya's random walk and gambler's ruin: interpretation in higher dimensions

Tags: probability, random-walk

I've read that Polya coined the term "Random Walk." He analyzed the 1-dimension example and proved that the chances of returning to any point on the line is ultimately 100%. This is how one can think of a gambler's ruin: a person playing a fair random game against a casino will eventually lose all his money.

Now, Polya also showed that this scheme breaks down in higher dimensions. For instance, in the 3 dimensional lattice, the player has a lower chance of going back to its starting point (0.34, although I realized in my research that there is no closed form answer for higher dimensions).

**Question:** how can we understand the gambler analogy in the context of Polya's higher dimension examples? Does the case for the 3-dimensional lattice mean that for example somehow playing in 3 casinos with 3 different currencies lowers the risk of ruin?

**p.s.** *This is not for gambling. I have never played at a casino, nor intend to... I'm just fascinated with the topic and have researched it as much as I could as a non-mathematician. Thanks for any insights!*

Answer (score 2):

In one dimension, "returning to the origin" and "running out of money" are one and the same. In more dimensions, "returning to the origin" corresponds to "simultaneously having a balance of zero dollars at every casino". In contrast, ruin might be thought of as having a net balance of zero dollars. Ruin still happens with 100% probability.